# Hiding the sidebar on mobile devices to make the theme responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, blogger

I'm trying to hide the right sidebar on the mobile version only so that the theme becomes more responsive on smaller devices.

Here is my code:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:750px) {

  .column-right-outer {
   width: 100% !important;
  }
}
```

```
<meta expr:content='data:blog.isMobile         ? &quot;width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0&quot;         : &quot;width=1100&quot;' name='viewport'/>
```

I'm also tried:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:750px) {

  .sidebar-right {
   width: 100% !important;
  }
}
```

```
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

To hide an element you should use `display: none` attribute. Try using the following rules:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 750px) {
  .column-right-outer {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

You can learn more about the `display` attribute [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It succeeded in hiding the right sidebar, but it leaves a blank space on the right. How can I fix it?

Comment: @nvrtr from what I see, the layout of the website is complex and it may require significant changes to the layout to achieve the desired view. I'd recommend to spend some time to analyze the structure of the page and try to manipulate the structure with HTML and CSS.

Comment: I have fixed the blank space using this code: @media screen and (max-device-width: 768px) {.main-inner .column-center-inner {width: 750px;background:#ffffff;float: none;}}